# Compare a value to a vector of values and return the match in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can any one tell me how to return a matched value to a comparison between a value and a column vector in MATLAB. So lets say the value to be compared is 200 and I got a column vector:

```
a = [21; 32; 433; 54; 42;]
```

I want to find which element in the vector `a` returns the match for the comparison `200 <= a`

If I do: `x = any(200 <= a)` the value of `x` will be `0` or `1` based on if the condition satisfy. But if I want to know which value in vector `'a'` satisfied the condition how can I find that out? In this case element 3 and value is 433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are good, but `find` is unnecessary.  Whenever possible, use logical indexing instead.  Seeing `200 <= a` is a bit strange for me.  I like seeing the variable on the left side, so this is the same as saying `a >= 200`.  In any case, you can do this:

```
vals = a(200 <= a);
```

`200 <= a` would return a logical vector where `1` denotes that the element satisfies the condition you're looking for and `0` would mean that the condition isn't satisfied.  If we displayed `200 <= a`, this is what we get:

```
>> 200 <= a

ans =

     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
```

This means that only the third element satisfies your criteria.  If we used this logical vector and indexed into `a`, we would return only those elements that satisfied your condition from `a`.  As such, we would get:

```
vals = 

433
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to get a vector of indices that satisfy the condition.

The following command returns the value at the index found to meet the criteria.

```
a(find(a >= 200))

ans =

     433
```

Likewise, a <= 200:

```
a(find(a <= 200))

ans =

    21
    32
    54
    42
```

As @David points out in the comments, you don't need to use the `find` command, but it works just the same.

Comment: The `find` is unnecessary, `a(a<=200)` works just the same as `a(find(a<=200))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inefficiency in using "find". Thanks @David

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as follows:

```
positions = find(200<=a); %// all positions satisfying condition
values = a(positions); %// values at those positions
```